# ASP.NET - Internal messaging system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a messaging system in my Web application similar to the one Chase and Facebook have on their websites.  Should I develop this on my own, or should I find a 3rd party control or other solution?  Would google provide some sort of API to make this easy?  I'm leaning towards developing this on my own because it probably won't involve too much but wanted to know my options.

All suggestions/comments are appreciated!

Comment: do you want to build a chat or the usual messaging ?

Comment: Not a chat, more like the usual messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it would be much better to build a messaging system of your own.